# Scale Landscape WebView to Fit Width and Height

Tags: android, android-webview

I have a WebView that always displays in landscape mode. It displays a website that has been set up so that the content is always fully visible (i.e. no vertical or horizontal scrollbars) as long as the user's resolution is at least 800 x 600. If I load this WebView on a tablet that has a resolution of 1024 x 600, I have to scroll vertically in order to see the whole thing (since Android's built-in navigation bar at the bottom takes up 48 pixels of vertical space). Similarly, if I load this WebView on a phone that has a resolution of 640 x 360, I have to scroll both horizontally and vertically in order to see the whole thing. Finally, if I load this WebView on a tablet that has a resolution of 1280 x 800, I don't have to scroll in either direction (which is good), but the website looks too small because there's so much extra space around the 800 x 600 design.

How can I make this website scale to fit on any of these three devices? In other words, keeping in mind that Android's built-in navigation bar at the bottom takes up 48 pixels of vertical space, the tablet that has a resolution of 1024 x 600 should scale the WebView to 92% so that the 800 x 600 design fits and the tablet that has a resolution of 1280 x 800 should scale the WebView to 125.3% so that the 800 x 600 design fits.

I've read about using the CSS `zoom` property to do the scaling, but have seen problems with this. An example is with the way text gets rendered sometimes. I think scaling the WebView natively rather than with CSS might make it perform better.

Answer (score 0):

You can make sure you won't scroll "sideways" by setting a [viewport meta-tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag). Scaling it vertically to fit is usually going to be a bad idea - is your layout really sufficiently flexible to handle *every* aspect ratio on every device? If you simply want do display something "at the bottom" used CSS fixed positioning instead.